# how to check whether an element in the row exists somewhere in other column but not the same row

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table as following

```
--------------------------
| REPO | USER | FOLLOWER |
--------------------------
|  A   |   1  |    3     |
|  A   |   2  |    4     |
|  A   |   3  |    6     |
|  B   |   2  |    7     |
|  B   |   4  |    2     |
|  C   |   5  |    3     |
|  C   |   2  |    6     |
|  C   |   6  |    5     |
--------------------------
```

Now, I want to only those rows where USER follows another USER for 
same REPO. 
i.e. I want rows where elements in FOLLOWER is also in USER for same 
REPO.

OUTPUT should be like...

```
--------------------------
| REPO | USER | FOLLOWER |
--------------------------
|  A   |   1  |    3     |
|  B   |   4  |    2     |
|  C   |   6  |    5     |
|  C   |   2  |    6     |
--------------------------
```

Thank You :)

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: No attempt shown.

Comment: what database you use? or this is just abstract sql question? the answer can really depend on what db you are using

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I am getting table from Google BigQuery and i am using it in databricks

Comment: so do you need BigQuery SQL or not? Asking as it was tagged in your original question. Please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.repo = t.repo and t2.follower = t.user);
```

Comment: Thanks. But this is not filtering according to the repo as well. It is taking row even when the user's follower is not itself the user for the same repo.

Comment: @Shaily . . . ."I want to only those rows where USER follows another USER for same REPO".  Those are your words, and this answer does that.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the output actually be as follows, i.e. 4 rows?

```
--------------------------
| REPO | USER | FOLLOWER |
--------------------------
|  A   |   1  |    3     |
|  B   |   4  |    2     |
|  C   |   6  |    5     |
|  C   |   2  |    6     |
--------------------------
```